# How to port patches created for older kernel version to new version without changing the original maintainer

Tags: linux-kernel, yocto, patch

While building `yocto` images for various SOCs, `patches` are used to add the internal changes to the `mainline kernel`. When a new kernel version releases, sometimes the old patches fail at a couple of `hunks` (say 2 out of 6). Now, I want a way to preserve the older patch with `maintainer name`, `subject` or other metadata. But I cannot find any tool which can do this.

I have used `rediff` from `patchutils`. It works fine for adding or removing  new lines and even removing hunks but it fails if the new change is not in line with the patch. So, is there any tool or a way, the kernel developers maintain the patches?

Comment: `git` is the tool you're looking for.

Comment: Quite often the the source is not fetched from git. And even if it is, I don't know how to preserve previous maintainer info using git format-patch. One way I am thinking according to your comment is apply the older patch by rejecting the failed hunks and create a new patch for the failed hunks. Is that so @OleksandrKravchuk

Comment: `git format-patch` preserves author information

Comment: `git am` can be used to import patches in email format (for example, as produced by `git format-patch`). If there are collisions, there will be an opportunity to edit the files, `git add` the edited files and then `git am --continue` to continue.

Comment: @IanAbbott thank you for the insight. I was also thinking on the similar lines, but needed an opinion or suggestion. For now I am satisfied with this being the answer for this question.